# SQL Use alias in Where statement

Tags: sql

I wounder how I could use an alias in a where statement.

Example :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3)  AS Col1
FROM MyTable
WHERE Col1 = 'MySearch'
```

I use MSSQL 2005

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Not possible, but you can do the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3)  AS Col1
FROM MyTable
WHERE SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3) = 'MySearch'
```

No subqueries or hacks required

Comment: But what if the function that creates col1 is demanding. Then you run it twice?(substring 4 times in this case)

Comment: And, you're duplicating code.  The statement in the select clause is the same as the one in the where clause, which doubles the effort to maintain.

Answer (score 75):

You can use "having" instead of "where".

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3)  AS Col1
FROM
    MyTable
HAVING
    Col1 = 'MySearch'
```

Having do a "where" after execution of the query.
Be careful to use it in the right conditions to have no performance problem.

Comment: This is the easiest to implement and most versatile solution. I don't know why it isn't voted up more.

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER.

Comment: This does not work for me. Are you sure this is the right answer?

Comment: HAVING only works on aggregate functions in MS SQL Server. Tested on 2012 and 2016.

Comment: Note that `HAVING` comes *after* `WHERE`, in case you also still want to put clauses in the where section.

Answer (score 22):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3) AS Col1 FROM MyTable)
WHERE Col1 = 'MySearch'
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3)  AS Col1
  FROM MyTable
)
WHERE Col1 = 'MySearch'
```

(I know this works in Oracle, I believe it is standard SQL and would work in MSSQL.)

Comment: It's likely to be slower though, if the inner query becomes complex.

Comment: in postgresql we need to name the inner subquery with `as smth` before the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM ( SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3) AS Col1 ) AS x
WHERE Col1 = 'MySearch'
```

Answer (score 3):

With PostgreSQL 9.3+ OR Oracle 12c, there is now lateral join that allows creating an alias.

Lateral joins are joints inside witch you can reference preceding tables.

```
SELECT col1, col2,col3
FROM MyTable m
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(m.Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3)  AS Col1 
) x ON true
WHERE Col1 = 'MySearch'
```

With this syntax, you don't have to use '*' that can be non-performing or recopy all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible, but maybe you can take a look on Common Table Expressions over SQL 2005

Like this:

```
WITH MyCTE( Col1) AS
(
SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3)  AS Col1
FROM MyTable
)
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
WHERE Col1 = 'MySearch'
```

Answer (score 1):

use a view or a derived table.

Using a derived table, your example would look like:

```
select col1 
from 
(SELECT SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3)  AS Col1
FROM MyTable) 
where col1='Mysearch'
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using alias won't make your query any faster as SQL optimizer is not as dumb as you think, so I'd just repeat the SUBSTRING expression again.

Comment: For me, He is looking a way for doing the query's more readable

Comment: That's a bit a violation of the DRY principle, isn't it ?  
When you modify the select clause, you've to make sure to modify the WHERE as well ...

Comment: Adding a subquery or using Having will make the query more complex which is worse that repeating such a simple expression twice.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can't - you can do this

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3)  AS Col1
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE 
    SUBSTRING(Column1, 1, 4) + SUBSTRING(Column1, 4, 3) = 'MySearch'
```