# DQL associations and lat lon distance

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dql

entity `A` has a field `name`

entity `B` has a field `city`

entity `C` has fields `lat` and `lon`

entity `A` has a one to many association to entity `B` named `bees`

entity `B` has a many to one association to entity `C` named `cees`

Now i want to select all `A` entity's that are within X kilometers from point Y.

X = 20

Y = lat:52.25 , lon:4.53

DQL:
`SELECT a, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(52.25) ) * cos( radians( c.lat ) ) * cos( radians( c.lon ) - radians(4.53) ) + sin( radians(52.25) ) * sin( radians( c.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.bees b LEFT JOIN b.cees c WHERE distance < 20`

When i execute this DQL i get:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT m0_.name AS name0, m0_.id AS id11, (6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(52.25)) * COS(RADIANS(p1_.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(p1_.lon) - RADIANS(4.53)) + SIN(RADIANS(52.25)) * SIN(RADIANS(p1_.lat)))) AS sclr12, FROM table_a m0_ LEFT JOIN table_b m2_ ON m0_.id = m2_.a_id LEFT JOIN table_c p1_ ON m2_.b_id = p1_.id WHERE sclr12 < 20':

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr12' in 'where clause'`
```

What am i doing wrong here?
Any help is much appreciated!

Yoram

Comment: In your original statement you say `distance < 20` and in your code you say `sclr12 < 20`. You have no column named `sclr12`

Comment: Exactly, but the thing is when i execute the DQL it changes it to what you see in the error. As you can see in the SQL in the error instead of naming the distance calculation `distance` it is now named `sclr12` but it still says the column `sclr12` does not exist.. `SELECT ... (6371 * ACOS( ... )) AS sclr12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just cannot refer to an alias in the `where` clause.

You will probably find a solution here: [SQL Use alias in Where statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715462/sql-use-alias-in-where-statement)