# hql spatial query with custom object wrapper

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, spatial-query

I am trying to get all points within a specified radius using hql. My query:

```
select NEW package_name.SearchListingVO( li, (distance_search_query) as distance ) from Listing li WHERE distance < 10000
```

SearchListingVO is just a pojo containing:

```
private Listing listing;
private Double distance;
```

I get this error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'

so, how can I access distance in WHERE (or HAVING) clause?

Comment: As you have given Listing an alias shouldn't it be `li.distance < 1000`

Comment: distance is not a property of listing class (and not a column in listing table). That's the reason I have to wrap it in SearchListingVO pojo.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood the question. What about running the distance_search_query in the where caluse as suggested [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715462/sql-use-alias-in-where-statement) So you would have to do `WHERE (distance_search_query) < 1000`

Comment: yes that works, thx. does this mean I have to I have to repeat the whole distance_search_query in ORDER BY too? All I wanted was ... WHERE distance < 10000 ORDER BY distance

Comment: I'm afraid so. Although it is not recommended you could try ordering it by column number `ORDER BY 1`