# Sequelize complex aggregate attribute in where and order

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

Hello I'm trying to use Sequelize to perform location based queries, and I'm having a nightmare!

I'm trying to generate the SQL:

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians([user-latitude])) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians([user-longitude])) + sin(radians([user-latitude])) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance FROM myModel HAVING distance <= 25 ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

where [user-latitude] and [user-longitude] are variables. So far I've got this:

```
myModel.findAll({
    attributes: [
        '*',
        [`(3959 * acos(cos(radians(${user-latitude})) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(${user-longitude})) + sin(radians(${user-latitude})) * sin(radians(latitude))))`, 'distance'],
    ],
    where: {
        distance: {
            $lte: 25,
        },
     },
    order: [
        ['distance', 'ASC'],
    ],
    limit: 10,
    offset: 0,
});
```

which generates:

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians([user-latitude])) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians([user-longitude])) + sin(radians([user-latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS `distance` FROM `myModels` AS `myModel` WHERE `myModel`.`distance` <= 15 ORDER BY `myModel`.`distance` ASC LIMIT 0, 10;
```

which doesn't work because `myModel`.`distance` is not a field. Is there a way to make this work without using raw queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use alias field in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` statement, only in the `ORDER BY`. You must repeat your statement in the `WHERE` clause instead using alias (just as it is explained in [SQL Use alias in Where statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715462/sql-use-alias-in-where-statement)).

What is more, the error you obtained happens because when you used field `distance` in the `where` and `order` attributes, Sequelize automatically treated it as a field of `myModel` instead your `alias`, so you need to write it literally so it won't be treated as a column of table you select.

```
myModel.findAll({
    attributes: {
        include: [[`(3959 * acos(cos(radians(${user-latitude})) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(${user-longitude})) + sin(radians(${user-latitude})) * sin(radians(latitude))))`, 'distance']]
    },
    where: sequelize.where(
        sequelize.literal(`(3959 * acos(cos(radians(${user-latitude})) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(${user-longitude})) + sin(radians(${user-latitude})) * sin(radians(latitude))))`),
        '<=',
        25
    ),
    order: 'distance ASC',
    limit: 10,
    offset: 0
});
```

`sequelize` in this case is your instance of Sequelize.

Comment: I was aware of the differences between 'where' and 'having', as their functionality differs between mysql and sqlite which we use for production and development respectively. Will test the code and get back to you :)

Comment: The '*' in attributes doesn't appear to return the other columns of the table when used through sequelize. Is it possible to get all other columns, as if attributes were not specified, without listing all of them?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I didn't notice that. I have updated the answer, now it should return all model fields + the additional distance field.

Comment: I was tried many ways to apply where condition. Finally I found the conclusion here. Thank you.