# how to find near by stores from user's current("location") provide with latitude and longitude

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to find near by store from user's current location by providing 3 parameters like user_id,latitude and longitude.

"Store table" contains all the details about the store likes name, address,latitude,longitude and so on.

So I would like to fetch all the stores which are near by.

I have tried this but it gives me syntax error...

These are the parameters:

```
latitude = 49.4084659,
longitude = 8.834348800000043,
user_id = 1

const query = `
    (
        3959 * acos(
            cos( radians(49.4084659) ) * cos( radians( store_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( store_logitude ) - radians(8.834348800000043) )
            +
            sin( radians(49.4084659) ) * sin( radians( store_latitude ) )
        )
    ) AS distance FROM store WHERE user_id IN (
        SELECT \`Follows\`.receiver_id FROM \`follows\` AS \`Follows\` WHERE \`Follows\`.user_id=${user_id} and \`Follows\`.status="accept"
    ) HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
`;

store.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [{
            user_id: {
                [Op.in]: [
                    sequelize.literal(query)
                ]
            }
        }, {
            user_id: user_id
        }]
    }
});
```

It gives me syntax errorr....

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
        'AS distance FROM stores WHERE user_id IN (SELECT `Follows`.receiver_id FROM `foll' at line 1
```

This MYSQL query work fine and gives me the required result..

```
 SELECT store_id,user_id,store_name, 
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(19.1250432) ) * cos( radians( store_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( store_logitude ) - radians(72.93173759999999) ) + sin(radians(19.1250432) ) * sin( radians( store_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM stores WHERE user_id IN (SELECT receiver_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = 1 AND status ="accept") OR user_id = 1 HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Can someone convert this into Sequelize query....

Comment: I'd say the first step is to break that up into multiple lines and reformat it into something readable!  It's too hard to see what's wrong with the code in its current form.

Comment: I did just notice one typo, "distnace" instead of "distance".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYSQL QUERY

```
SELECT store_id,user_id,store_name, 
    (   
        3959 * acos( cos( radians(49.4084659) ) * cos( radians( store_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( event_logitude ) - radians(8.834348800000043) ) 
        + 
       sin(radians(49.4084659) ) * sin( radians( store_latitude ) ) ) 
    ) AS distance FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (
       SELECT receiver_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = 1 AND status ="accept") OR user_id = 1 
       HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Above query can be converted in sequelize as

```
const lat = 49.4084659;
const lon = 8.834348800000043;
const user_id = 1;
const km = 6371;

const query = '
        ( '+km+' * acos( cos( radians('+lat+') ) * cos( radians( store_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( store_logitude ) - radians('+lon+') ) 
            + 
            sin( radians('+lat+') ) * sin( radians( store_latitude ) ) ) 
        )';

store.findAll({
    where:{
        [Op.or]:[{
            user_id:{[Op.in]:[
                sequelize.literal('(SELECT `Follows`.receiver_id FROM `follows` AS `Follows` WHERE `Follows`.user_id='+user_id+' and `Follows`.status="accept")')]}},
                {user_id:user_id}
                             ]
         },

    attributes: { include : [[sequelize.literal(query),'distance']]},
    where: sequelize.where(sequelize.literal(query), '<=',25),
    order: sequelize.col('distance'),
    limit: 15,
    offset: 0
})
```

Unfortunately you cannot use alias field in the WHERE or HAVING statement, only in the ORDER BY. You must repeat your statement in the WHERE clause instead using alias (just as it is explained in [SQL Use alias in Where statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715462/sql-use-alias-in-where-statement).)

Also visit this for more clarification : [Sequelize complex aggregate attribute in where and order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634043/sequelize-complex-aggregate-attribute-in-where-and-order)

Answer (score 0):

Your `AS` has no space before it.

```
 ) ) )AS distance
```

Like @kshetline suggested, I think if you simplify your code formatting a bit, it might make these things easier to spot.

Comment: I have reformatted my code....I have tried giving space between             
  ) ) )AS distance   to  ) ) ) AS distance                                                                   but still it gives me the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

To learn to debug your problem, please start by properly formatting your code. Take a look:

```js
const query = `
    (
        3959 * acos(
            cos( radians(19.1250432) ) * cos( radians( store_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( store_logitude ) - radians(72.93173759999999) )
            +
            sin( radians(19.1250432) ) * sin( radians( store_latitude ) )
        )
    ) AS distance FROM store WHERE user_id IN (
        SELECT \`Follows\`.receiver_id FROM \`follows\` AS \`Follows\` WHERE \`Follows\`.user_id=${user_id} and \`Follows\`.status="accept"
    ) HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20
`;

store.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [{
            user_id: {
                [Op.in]: [
                    sequelize.literal(query)
                ]
            }
        }, {
            user_id: user_id
        }]
    }
});
```

So much better!