# Subquery where condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some questions about `where` condition parameters while using subqueries.

```
select 
    id, name, 
    (select count(*) from table2) count 
from 
    table1
```

Output is

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | name        | count |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | abc         |    13 |
|  2 | efg         |    15 |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

I would like to use this count is where condition like this :

```
select 
    id, name, 
    (select count(*) from table2) count 
from 
    table1 
where 
    count = 15
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'count' in 'where clause'

I don't want to use an entire subquery in where clause. How can we solve this issue?

Comment: [SQL Use alias in Where statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715462/sql-use-alias-in-where-statement)

Answer (score 4):

Use a derived table:

```
select * from
(
    select id,name, (select count(*) from table2) count from table1
) dt
where count = 15
```

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
select id,name, (select count(*) from table2) as count
from table1
```

*does not* return the results that you have specified.  How do I know?  The count is different in the two rows.  If this were the query, the count would be the same.

For your given query, the obvious solution is to move the subquery to the `from` clause:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.cnt
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from table2 t2) t2
where t2.cnt = 15;
```

However, your query is probably a correlated subquery.  In that case the best solution is to use `apply` (which can be used for the uncorrelated case as well):

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.cnt
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
where t2.cnt = 15;
```